# scripting language for my program that can be executed line by line

Tags: c++, qt, scripting, pyqt

i am looking to integrate a scripting language into my program, such as pythio. To be clear, by that i mean that my native application is running, then the user click "execute script" and a script executes within the program to do stuff.

A big requirement is that the user can see the script, execute it line-by-lin, set breakpoints in the script and preferably also change the content of variables. Essentially, i would like to run a complete debugger within my application.

Is that possible?

All the scriping language binding were either meant to a) access native code from within a script (ie script loads program, not the other way around) or b) could only be executed in one go without user interaction.

Comment: What is the problem? You can invoke external processes in native applications. You could invoke an external debugger for that language, or if it does not exist, you need to write that for sure, but that is regardless of the invokation.

Comment: well, for example when i use SWIG+boost:python, i can call py:exec on single statements or files, but i cant execute a file line by line or inspect its variables at runtime.


I dont see how i can bring in an external debugger?

Comment: Every script file is executed line by line, but really, just learn what a debugger is and try to look for a suitable one. The whole point of debuggers is this.

Comment: i know what a debugger is, i just dont see how i can use one when i am embedding python code in my application.

Comment: There is really nothing magical about it, you just invoke the python script with the debugger as desired rather than invoking it directly. Of course, you can reinvent the debugger in your application, too, but that is much more work than using a ready-made. I am not sure if you can find a debugger separated into a library and an application to avoid the invokation. That would be neater.

Comment: i would be perfectly happy with an external debugger. The python script calls back into the program that embeds it to query runtime data of the program. I dont see how i can possibly attach an external debugger to it. All i can do is py::exec() and use the result of the entire script.


If there is another way, taht would be exactly what i am lookin for, please share. :)

Comment: I do not follow. You asked whether it is possible to run the script _from the binary_, and not the other way around. Now, you are asking if it is possible. Sure, it is, but it is a different topic. Check gdb, cdb, etc, whatever you environment, that you have not shared, have.

Comment: I have a program written in c++ (cross-platform). This program exports certain functions to python, that depend on the state of the program. Now the program executes a user supplied python script via boost::python. This is done by calling py::exec(...). py::exec() executes the file in one go (!) and returns a result. In addition to that result the script may have done changes to the c++ programs state via the functions that were made available to it.


Now, the aim is to replace that py::exec() call by a debugger of some sort, that allows a line by line execution. i just dont see how.

Comment: You still have not shared your platform details, really, but look into QProcess if you wish to debug the script from the binary, and just subprocess in python for the other way around.

Comment: Do you want to execute a script line by line, at each line you can print locals etc? Or do you just want to break into the python debugger when the script raises an exception? Or both?

Comment: It's a cross-platform developed in Qt5. Exactly, i would like to step over it line by line and print its variables. So that the user may observe the effect of the script. I've been studying the python C api, but i still dont see how i can attach a debugger in that way.